# Discount on combination of 2 products from different categories

Tags: category, discount

I need to make a discount rule that only applies if products of Categories 2 & 5 are combined, and not applies if one of them is alone in the shopping cart

so seperated:
product from cat. 2 = €10
product from cat. 6 = €15

both combined are (€10+€15)- discount(20%) = €20
but if there is a product from cat 3 & 6 then there will be no discount.

hope this explains my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try with this combination:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    If total quantity  equals or greater than  1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
        Category  is one of  2 

    If total quantity  equals or greater than  1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
        Category  is one of  5
```